# Compactness of diagonal operator $ T_\alpha(x_1, x_2,x_3...)=(\alpha_1x_1, \alpha_2x_2,\alpha_3 x_3,...)$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $\alpha=(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3...)$ a sequence of complex numbers  that converges to zero.

I need to show the compactness of the diagonal operator $T_\alpha:l^2\to l^2$ defined by $$ T_\alpha(x_1, x_2,x_3...)=(\alpha_1x_1, \alpha_2x_2,\alpha_3 x_3,...)$$

For this:

I define the sequence the operator of finite range $T_n$ so that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$$T_n(x_1, x_2,x_3...)=(\alpha_1x_1, \alpha_2x_2,\alpha_3 x_3,..., \alpha_n x_n,0,0,0,... )$$

I need to show that $T_n\to T_\alpha$ and then $T_\alpha$ is compact.

I have that $$\|(T_\alpha-T_n)(x_1, x_2,x_3...)\|^2=\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty|\alpha _j x_j|^2$$

But I dont know how to conclude that $\|T_\alpha-T_n\|$.

I think that I must limit the sum by an expression in terms of $n$ using that the sequence $\alpha=(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3...)$ converges to zero. But I do not know how to do it. I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Since $a_n\to0$, there exists $n_0$ such that $|a_n|<\varepsilon^2$ whenever $n>n_0$. So, for $n>n_0$,
$$
\|(T-T_n)x\|^2=\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty|a_jx_j|^2\leq \varepsilon^2\,\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty|x_j|^2
\leq\varepsilon^2\,\|x\|^2.
$$
This shows that $\|T-T_n\|<\varepsilon$ whenver $n>n_0$, so $\lim T_n=T$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\|(T_\alpha-T_n)(x)\|^2=\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty|\alpha _j x_j|^2 \leq \left(\sup_{m>n} |a_m|^2\right)\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty|x_j|^2 \leq \left(\sup_{m>n} |a_m|^2\right) \|x\|^2$$

Therefore, $$\|T_\alpha-T_n\| \leq \sup_{m>n} |a_m|$$